# CodeIgniter Curl post taking 16 seconds

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

My code:

```
private function getServerInfo($servers){
    $result = array();

    foreach ($servers as $key => $value) {

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://mcapi.de/api/server-query/".$servers[$key]->ip.":".$servers[$key]->port."");

        $result[$key] = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

        curl_close($ch);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to check 16 server IPs and each one takes 1 second.

Comment: And what do you expect to get?

Comment: a faster result, 16 seconds to load page with results is alot.

Comment: Servers are checked one after another. So 16 servers * 1 sec each is ok.

Comment: Rly? In browser i get result in less than 100ms (https://mcapi.de/api/server-query/45.126.210.34/25590)

Comment: Try with json decoding outside the loop.